# Curve and array modifier is distorting the shape

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have a Hexagon turned into a curve shape, and I'm trying to make the sphere go follow the curvature, I add the array and curve modifier then select the Hexagon but the sphere shape gets distorted. I also added more segments in case it would correct this issue, but the sphere shape becomes even worse.

How can I fix this?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Here's the file, I did manage to make some progress, but the spheres on the corner are jammed up, I think it was distorting the sphere because the pivot point wasnt in the centre of the world. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=qseRKKZz" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/qseRKKZz/)

Comment: You must have applied the scale of your curve, you probably need to reset the curve vertices radius to 1 (go in Edit mode, select all, open the N panel and set the Mean Radius to 1)

Comment: I had a look at the mean radius but that's not what's causing the deformation of the spheres. https://ibb.co/YTT1F2s

Comment: I don't know if you can avoid that, Curve modifier will deform the object by definition, when it's on an angle the deformation is more visible

Comment: I believe this is the solution based on @Lemons response I did it with Dupliverts, not exactly the way it was shown in the GIF animation, but seems spot on. I believe I can use this as a correct answer? https://ibb.co/3R282rD